# Get emails from imap server using coldfusion 7

Tags: coldfusion, imap

I have tried this example http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1056-ColdFusion-CFPOP-My-First-Look.htm, but it retrieve emails from POP server. Is there any similar way to do for IMAP mail server?

I know there is new  tag in Coldfusion 9 but I can't use it as I am working in Coldfusion 7.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this? http://imapwatcher.riaforge.org/

Comment: Thank you for replying sir. I am your big fan. 
Actually Ray I finally decided to use cfpop only, but will try your link sometime in this weekend. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but I found this imap.cfc which should work with your coldfusion version. It is no longer under active development but maybe it just work ;)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cfimap-cfc/

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had tried that on CF 8 for getting gmail emails but it got me some error. I finally decide to use cfpop.
Thanks again